# How to force a subclass as a parameter (or disallow parent class as parameter)

Tags: java

TL;DR Is there a way to force a method to receive a subclass and not a parent class?

Say I have an interface like:

```
interface MyInterface<T extends A>{
    process(A a)
}
```

and class

```
abstract class A<T extends A>{
    MyInteface<T>[] processors
}
```

And two subclasses B and C such as:

```
class B extends A<B>{}
class C extends A<C>{}
```

I want to make it so that an implementation of MyInterface can do something like:

```
class MyImplementation implements MyInterface<B>, MyInterface<C>{
    process(B)
    process(C)
}
```

I believe this is not possible because the compiler wouldn't be able to tell what to do if you pass the superclass, A, to MyImplementation.

Is it possible to force MyImplementation to only receive subclasses? If not, how would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) in Java: At runtime, the type information associated with generics is no longer available. For example:

```
List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

// At runtime, these types actually look like this:
List numbers = new ArrayList();
List strings = new ArrayList();
```

Thus, a single class cannot implement the same generic interface more than once with different generic type parameters. Ergo, `class MyImplementation implements MyInterface<B>, MyInterface<C> { /* ... */ }` will fail during compilation. Doing so results in the following error:

> The interface `MyInterface` cannot be implemented more than once with
>   different arguments: `MyInterface<C>` and
>   `MyInterface<B>`

Once the types are erased, this class amounts to `class MyImplementation implements MyInterface, MyInterface { /* ... */ }`, which is obviously not permissible in Java.

---

**Alternative**

It appears as though you are looking for the functionality of the call to change depending on which class is used to process the elements (`MyInterface<B>`, `MyInterface<C>`, etc.) as well as which element is processed (`A`, `B`, `C`, etc.). This is called [double-dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) and is closely related to the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example). In the context of your problem, you can do the following:

```
public interface Element {
    public void accept(Processor processor);
}

public class A implements Element {

    @Override
    public void accept(Processor processor) {
        processor.process(this);
    }
}

public class B implements Element {

    @Override
    public void accept(Processor processor) {
        processor.process(this);
    }
}

public interface Processor {
    public void process(A a);
    public void process(B b);
}

public class RedProcessor implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(A a) {
        System.out.println("Red processor got an A");
    }

    @Override
    public void process(B b) {
        System.out.println("Blue processor got an A");
    }

}

public class BlueProcessor implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(A a) {
        System.out.println("Blue processor got an A");
    }

    @Override
    public void process(B b) {
        System.out.println("Blue processor got an A");
    }

}
```

This code can be tested using the following:

```
Processor processor = new RedProcessor();
A a = new A();
processor.process(a);
```

Varying both the `Processor` implementation (e.g. `RedProcessor` or `BlueProcessor`) and the `Element` implementation (e.g. `A` or `B`) results in different output. Since the result depends on the `Processor` and the `Element`, this technique is called *double*-dispatch.